# Check if both radio boxes are selected?

Tags: jquery

So I wrote the following jquery:

```
$('#consent_for_research_no, #consent_for_global_sharing_no').on('change', function() {
    var consentForResearchIsChecked      = $('#consent_for_research_no').is(':checked');
    var consentForGlobalSharingIsChecked = $('#consent_for_global_sharing_no').is(':checked');

    if (consentForResearchIsChecked && consentForGlobalSharingIsChecked) {
        console.log('hello?');
    }
});
```

The goal is to get to the `console.log` when and ONLY when both are checked. The console spits out **no** errors and does nothing when I do selected both.

The HTML in question is:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="consent_for_global_sharing" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Consent For Global Sharing <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#consentForGlobalSharing"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></a></label>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="consent_for_global_sharing_yes">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" class="form-control" id="consent_for_global_sharing_yes" name="consent_for_global_sharing" value="1" {{ old('consent_for_global_sharing') === '1' ? 'checked': '' }}>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="consent_for_global_sharing_no">No</label>
        <input type="radio" class="form-control" id="consent_for_global_sharing_no" name="consent_for_global_sharing" value="0" {{ old('consent_for_global_sharing') === '0' ? 'checked': '' }}>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="consent_for_research" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Consent For Research <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#consentForResearch"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></a></label>
    <?php dump(old('consent_for_research')); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="consent_for_research_yes">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" class="form-control" id="consent_for_research_yes" name="consent_for_research" value="1" {{ old('consent_for_research') === '1' ? 'checked': '' }}>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="consent_for_research_no">No</label>
        <input type="radio" class="form-control" id="consent_for_research_no" name="consent_for_research" value="0" {{ old('consent_for_research') === '0' ? 'checked': '' }}>
    </div>
</div>
```

> incase any one is confused this is a laravel blade.

How do I get it such that **when both are selected it gets to the console.log?**

when I go into the console after selecting both and check the query: `$('#consent_for_research_no').is(':checked');` it shows true, same for the other one. Am I missing something with how I do the on change?

I should also be able to put an else statement to say if they are both not checked (that is they go from no to yes) then it should get into the else statement, but before I handle that I am asking how to get into the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('[name="consent_for_research"], [name="consent_for_global_sharing"]').on('click', function() {
    var consentForResearchIsChecked      = $('[name="consent_for_research"]:checked').val();
    var consentForGlobalSharingIsChecked = $('[name="consent_for_global_sharing"]:checked').val();
    if(consentForResearchIsChecked == 1 && consentForGlobalSharingIsChecked == 1) {
      console.log('both checked');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="consent_for_global_sharing" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Consent For Global Sharing <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#consentForGlobalSharing"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></a></label>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="consent_for_global_sharing_yes">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" class="form-control" id="consent_for_global_sharing_yes" name="consent_for_global_sharing" value="1" {{ old('consent_for_global_sharing') === '1' ? 'checked': '' }}>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="consent_for_global_sharing_no">No</label>
        <input type="radio" class="form-control" id="consent_for_global_sharing_no" name="consent_for_global_sharing" value="0" {{ old('consent_for_global_sharing') === '0' ? 'checked': '' }}>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="consent_for_research" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Consent For Research <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#consentForResearch"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></a></label>
    <?php dump(old('consent_for_research')); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="consent_for_research_yes">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" class="form-control" id="consent_for_research_yes" name="consent_for_research" value="1" {{ old('consent_for_research') === '1' ? 'checked': '' }}>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="consent_for_research_no">No</label>
        <input type="radio" class="form-control" id="consent_for_research_no" name="consent_for_research" value="0" {{ old('consent_for_research') === '0' ? 'checked': '' }}>
    </div>
</div>
```